# How to set values at runtime using Named templates in helm chart?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I created a simple helm chart using `helm create nginx-test` and it worked successfully

Is it possible to set the values `service.port` at run-time by calling a template function as mentioned below

`helm install --set service.port="{{ include changePortNo . }}" nginx-test .`

The named template `changePortNo` was defined in _helpers.tpl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't invoke Helm templates at that level.  In the command line you're showing, the `--set=...` argument will be processed by the shell, and so you can use things like environment variables and shell functions, but you can't directly invoke Helm code.

I suspect you're trying to set this here because the `helm create` template has this as a parameter.  If I were writing a chart from scratch, the port number of the Service wouldn't be something I'd customize.  You can change the `templates/service.yml` to call your function directly

```yaml
spec:
  ports:
    - port: {{ include "changePortNo" . }}
            {{/* not .Values.service.port */}}
```

In principle it would be possible to use the [`tpl`](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#using-the-tpl-function) function to allow passing a template string in the way you show.  This still would involve changing the `service.yml` to use `tpl`, in the same place.